# setState array update but not removing the previous

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a little question. Let's assume this code

```
 const [ChatDetailsRender, setChatDetailsRender] = useState([]);

 //ChatDetailsRender it s equal= {10,20}
 
 array=[1,2,3,4]

 array.forEach((nr)=>{
 setChatDetailsRender();
 //here some code to add the array for each value in useState})
```

This is some simple example about what i wanna do and i have some difficulties because i also have some database calls. Everything looks fine but how can i update ChatDetails useState without overwriting data? like just merge these 2 arrays. Sorry, i think this questions was already here but all i can find it's examples with objects in useState, and my example contains just an simple array. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concat the new value to the existing value while updating and use callback approach to set state.

```
const [ChatDetailsRender, setChatDetailsRender] = useState([]);

 //ChatDetailsRender it s equal= {10,20}
 
 array=[1,2,3,4]
 setChatDetailsRender(previousChatDetails => previousChatDetails.concat(array));
```